# How to disable multi-window in Android 12?

Tags: android

I am upgrading targetSDK to 31 (Android 12), and just realize that google enables multi-window for all large screen on Android 12.

As I tested, with the setting `resizeableActivity="false"`, my app is still resizable and can be put into multi-window mode. However, as my app does not support multi-window, each time I resize my app, it just relaunches all over again, which is of course not what I want.

Is there any possibility that I can disable multi-window on Android 12?

Here is the what stated in the [google document](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/multi-window-support):

> Android 12 makes multi-window mode standard behavior.
>
> > On large screens (sw >= 600dp), the platform supports all apps in multi-window mode regardless of app configuration. If resizeableActivity="false", the app is put into compatibility mode when necessary to accommodate display dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable multi window totally at this time, but you can prevent activity re-creation by setting `configChanges` to desired activity in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
```